# Memory Optimization in Prediction IO

Tags: memory-management, predictionio, memory-optimization

I am working on `naive bayes` and `logistic regression` using `prediction io`, it is great product. All are working fine. but when I build the prediction model and deploy, it gives java heap error so I gave this command `pio deploy -- --driver-memory 2G` and error removed. I have 4 models and all are taking 2GB. My question is how to optimize the memory uses in prediction io. I have 8GB RAM System and I have to build and deploy 7 different prediction models.

Thanks

Comment: Are you doing this on one machine?

Comment: Yes, will you suggest me optimize way.

Comment: PredictionIO is meant to scale vertically with more memory or horizontally with more cluster nodes.

On a single machine all you can do is make sure your ids take up as little memory as possible in the driver. Shorter ids will shave a little off memory useage but not a lot unless you have very long ids.

Comment: make sure your ids take up as little memory as possible in the driver. I am not getting your point. What is ids here. Can you please little bit explain it.